# Why I got an error config xml file when I used the same element?

Tags: xml, spring

```
<bean name="collection1" class="com.bean.Collection">
    <property name="array">
        <value>123</value>          
        <value>abc</value>
    </property>

    </bean>
```

I got an error at my second value element, the first one works well.

> Element : value Contains a string representation of a property value.
>   The property may be a string, or may be   converted to the required
>   type using the JavaBeans PropertyEditor machinery. This makes it
>   possible   for application developers to write custom PropertyEditor
>   implementations that can convert strings to   arbitrary target
>   objects. Note that this is recommended for simple objects only.
>   Configure more   complex objects by populating JavaBean properties
>   with references to other beans.
>
> Content Model : ()

Comment: Because a `property` can only have one `value`. Use `value="123,abc"` or wrap the values in a `list` tag.